# Microsoft Graph translateExchangeIds not returning the same id as EWS

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

I am working with both EWS and the Graph API.

I would like to create events (online meetings with skype/teams) in an calendar that is already available via EWS.

To match the calendar to the one available via Graph API i try to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids

The calendar i created has this id when returned by the FindFolder call:

```
<t:FolderId Id="AAMkAGNiY2YxMjY3LTUxYjgtNGI1Yy1hOTM2LTU4MTM5OTZiNjdjYgAuAAAAAABW2gY0kRG1SqggDTNZN6i8AQAPJkKZ1XJkQ6huFmcVa6XaAAGixNZ3AAA=" ChangeKey="..."/>
<t:DisplayName>Test</t:DisplayName>
```

I create a request to the graph api:

```
{
"inputIds": [
    "AAMkAGNiY2YxMjY3LTUxYjgtNGI1Yy1hOTM2LTU4MTM5OTZiNjdjYgAuAAAAAABW2gY0kRG1SqggDTNZN6i8AQAPJkKZ1XJkQ6huFmcVa6XaAAGixNZ3AAA="
],
"sourceIdType": "ewsId",
"targetIdType": "restId"}
```

and get the result

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.convertIdResult)",
"value": [
    {
        "sourceId": "AAMkAGNiY2YxMjY3LTUxYjgtNGI1Yy1hOTM2LTU4MTM5OTZiNjdjYgAuAAAAAABW2gY0kRG1SqggDTNZN6i8AQAPJkKZ1XJkQ6huFmcVa6XaAAGixNZ3AAA=",
        "targetId": "AAMkAGNiY2YxMjY3LTUxYjgtNGI1Yy1hOTM2LTU4MTM5OTZiNjdjYgAuAAAAAABW2gY0kRG1SqggDTNZN6i8AQAPJkKZ1XJkQ6huFmcVa6XaAAGixNZ3AAA="
    }
]
```

}

However, if i call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars i get a different id

```
        "id": "AAMkAGNiY2YxMjY3LTUxYjgtNGI1Yy1hOTM2LTU4MTM5OTZiNjdjYgBGAAAAAABW2gY0kRG1SqggDTNZN6i8BwBIq5JjIBY-RqWQllrF0GSkAAAAB353AAAPJkKZ1XJkQ6huFmcVa6XaAAGixNowAAA=",
        "name": "Test",
```

Is there a way to match the (ews) calendar i already have to the one returned by the Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, because I've never dug this deeply into the weeds on the Graph Ids, but you might try calling Graph with the header that selects "immutable ids."  I tried to find some details on what this actually means without much luck.

The header is:

```
request.Header("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"");
```

HTH, and if not, sorry for guessing.

Comment: Doesn't change anything, tried in in GraphExplorer.

It seems that i can just use the EWS id to retrieve a calendar, as long as i replace / with _ so that has been my workaround so far.